# Python's json dumps/loads make integer keys of my dict str

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

when i serialize and deserialize python built-in structure I'm expect output same as input

```
arr2 = [1,2,'3']
arr2_json = json.dumps(arr2)
json.loads(arr2_json)
```

Out[16]: [1, 2, '3']

BUT when I'm tring do it with dict I got str keys instead of integer

```
dict1 = {0: 'object0', '1': 'object2'}
json1 = json.dumps(dict1)
json.loads(json1)
```

Out[6]: {'0': 'object0', '1': 'object2'}

Notice keys must be [0, '1'] but actually are ['0', '1']

What is it? My misunderstanding or ussue in python

Python 3